# Render column in Data table with routerLink

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

In DataTable implementation,is it possible for me use routerLink here instead of href , routerLink renders a link but doesnt navigate to the page.

```
 render: (data: any, type: any, row: any, meta) => {
                return `
                    <a href="/store' + row.id + '/'+ storeid +'" title="View">
                        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
                    </a>
                `;                
        }
```

How to implement this the Angular 2/4 way ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and took me a while to find the answer. I solved it by using the rowCallBack option when declaring the datatable options, binding a click event to the row using jquery, and then using angular's router module.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-datatable',
  templateUrl: './my-datatable.component.html']
})
export class DataTableComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  rowClickHandler(data) {
    this.router.navigate(['store/' + data['id']]);
  }

  dataTableOptions = {
    rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | Object, index: number) =>{
      const self = this;
      jQuery('td', row).unbind('click');
      jQuery('td', row).bind('click', () => {
        self.rowClickHandler(data);
      });
    return row;
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

This link lead me to the answer.
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/row-click-event

I also had to install jquery with:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

import in the file or declare it in your `typings.d.ts` file

```
import * as jQuery from "jquery";
```

Comment: Using `jQuery` in `angular` is never recommended. You can use `javascript` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
<a [routerLink]="['/store', row.id]" title="View">
   <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: [ts] Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.

Comment: are you able to route properly when you go to '/store/:id' manually in your address bar?

Comment: Yes , actually this is specific to render function of data table which doesnt allow for dynamic binding with routerLink

Comment: can anyone help me , figure it out ?